# Umrah Visa from Australia on Foreign Passport

Tags: indian-citizens, australian-citizens, saudi-arabia

I and wife plan to travel to the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia for performing Umrah. While she's an Australian citizen I have an Indian passport and I am living with her, on a partner visa, in Australia.

I am unable to find information on how we can get visas for Umrah here in Australia. While she could apply online and get a tourist visa for herself that would let her perform Umrah as well, there is no such option for me.

What is the process for someone in my situation?

Comment: Are you actually residing in Australia?

Comment: Yes we're in Australia.

Comment: How many days are you planning to stay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ministry for the Hajj in Saudi Arabia [states](https://www.haj.gov.sa/Umra)

> > Umrah requirements based on arrival from
>
> Australia Dear Mu’tamir You can develop your Umrah trip directly
> through any of the approved platforms https://www.nusuk.sa/

Looking at the requirements (button on the upper-left of the Nusuk site) for an Australian citizen on the linked site, they have indeed the option to apply online or on arrival for that visa

---

For Indians, it is a bit more complicated :

Choosing India in the wizard, you have to state :

> Are you a US, UK or EU permanent residents or a US, UK or Schengen visa holder?

**IMPORTANT** : The **permanent resident** word means that a regular, time-limited, Residence Permit of Schengen and the UK will **not** work. A US Green Card, a UK Indefinite Leave to Remain, or an EU **long-term** residence permit will work for those purposes.

And

> > Are you a GCC resident?
>
> (GCC is a regional union comprising Bahrain, Kuwait, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, and the United Arab Emirates)

If it is an affirmative to the first, visa on arrival is available to you.
If it is an affirmative to the second, an e-visa is available to you.

---

If neither, you need to contact an [authorized travel agency](https://www.nusuk.sa/partners) and organize your Umrah for you as part of a package with your visa, you can't do it yourself

Comment: The OP is an Australian resident, so I don't see how either of those would apply?

Comment: Hadn't had the confirmation at answer time, and having a US/UK/Schengen visa is quite common, so I had to mention it @lambshaanxy. Especially with the 10-year-long US visas that are available to Indians

Comment: You don't state it in your answer but you're implying that the holding of "...or a US, UK or Schengen visa holder" is not valid for a visa on arrival. Is that true?

Comment: @mkennedy No, holding a US/UK/Schengen visa makes you eligible for VoA

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Weird! So permanent residence or a visitor visa works, but a residence permit doesn't?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, some countries have that mechanism, Mexico is the most *famous* of those